# Concurrency issue while calling rest web service in standalone java programme

Tags: java, multithreading, rest

I am trying to use fixed thread pool using executor framework. Each runnable instance submitted to the executor is worker thread which process a java result set. For every iteration of the result set I have to call rest webservice which used the oauth token. The oauth token is to be refreshed after every 50 min and need to be shared among all the runnable submitted to the executor.I am also using scheduled executor which execute after every 50 minutes but sometimes it is called correctly and some time not due to which the rest web service fails as it used the expired token in its header. I need to ensure that the scheduled service must be called after every 50 min without fail. But I am stuck on this. Also I need some mechanism that after the group of rest web service call is completed then only the new web service calls should be made while iterating the result set.

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executorPool = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
WorkerThread wt1=new WorkerThread(conn,Queries.getAddressInfo("AL"),oauth_token,restTemplate);
WorkerThread wt2=new WorkerThread(conn,Queries.getAddressInfo("AK"),oauth_token,restTemplate);
executorPool.execute(wt1);
executorPool.execute(wt2);

ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture =
scheduledExecutorService.schedule(new Runnable() {
    public void run()  {

        System.out.println("token service");

        String url="";
        try {
            url = WebServicePropertyFileReader.getOauthUrl()+String.format(urlToGetOauthToken, WebServicePropertyFileReader.getClientId(),
                    WebServicePropertyFileReader.getClientSecret());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Layer7Token token=restTemplate.postForObject(url, null, Layer7Token.class);
        GlobalTokenAccessor.oauth_token=token.getAccessToken();
    }
},
50,
TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: Also how could I ensure that I make only certain number of web service call in certain time say 75 request in 1 seconds and 76 the request should be only fired when the response for the previous request is completed

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues :
Schedule schedules it only one time.
You should use scheduleAtFixedRate to schedule periodic tasks. There is no guarantee that the thread will get scheduled within 50 minutes. So, you may want to schedule the refresh every 49 minutes or so. 
Secondly, you should control the access to the shared variable though a synchronized write and read methods. Otherwise, the read thread may read incorrect values.